# When can an 'untap' ability not untap?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let say I play [Leaden Fists](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Discussion.aspx?multiverseid=126139) on [Leech Bonder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=147406), can I pay my 1 blue mana and untap, or does Leaden Fist overide this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can untap Leech Bonder this way because the untapping is not occurring as part of the untap phase, which is what Leaden Fists is preventing.

That is, Leaden Fists is preventing the "normal" untap, not an activated ability untap.